# Connect to Unix File System using Java Program

Tags: java, unix, connection

I want to establish a connection with my UNIX file system using java program.. So that I can make some File I/O operations and normally I can connect using Putty.

How can I do the same using java program

I have the Host name, username,password and Port number

Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You need several things:

1. A server that takes commands (create directory, list directory, write data to a file, read data from a file) over the network. This server should listen to `port1` on `localhost`
2. You need to configure putty to forward `port2` on your local computer to `port1` on the server.
3. A local client which allows you to connect to `port2` on your local computer. Putty will tunnel any data send to `port2` to `port1` on the remote server and vice versa.

Or you get [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) which uses the SSH protocol (just like Putty) and maybe already does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pure Java implementation of SSH/SCP available: http://www.cleondris.ch/opensource/ssh2/

You can use its `SCPClient` or `SFTPv3Client` classes to work on the remote file system.

Documentation is available at http://www.cleondris.ch/opensource/ssh2/javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from Java, you can use [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/). It provides a common approach to dealing with files on all of the [supported file systems](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html). [SFTP](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html#SFTP) is one of the supported types which is most likely what you would need if you have been connecting with PuTTY.

Answer (score 0):

You need SSH client. There are various pure java SSH clients. Google "java ssh client" and try  any one of them. I used Jsch http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ and it worked fine for me.